# Query for computing yearweek

Tags: postgresql

I need to a help at query in such a way that in yearweek,in a year there are 52 weeks

2015 has 52 weeks but 2016 yearweek should start as 201601 that is the first week of year 2016, not as a continuation of 2015's 53rd week.

```
2015 jan 1--> 201501(1st week of 2015) likewise
2016 jan 1 --> 201601(1st week of 2016) it shouldnt be 201553(53rd week of 2015)
```

Comment: Yes offcourse @wingedpanther I need the query in such a way that 2016's first week should not be 2015's 53rd week. The continuation should not exsist as in after 2015's 52nd week, 2016's 1st week should not be 2015's 53rd week instead it should be 2016's 1st week i.e, 201601 and not 201553

Comment: He say about ISO 8601 week numbering

Comment: @incognito I don't think postgres out of the box meet your requirements. Postgres uses ISO 8601 week numbering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date So you should manually handle week number

Comment: @user1516873: Postgres supports both.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION fn_yearofweek (val DATE)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
SELECT extract(year FROM val)::TEXT || cast(floor((extract(doy FROM val) - 1) / 7) + 1 AS TEXT);
$$
LANGUAGE sql
```

Usage:

```
SELECT fn_yearofweek('2015-01-01')
      ,fn_yearofweek('2015-12-31')
      ,fn_yearofweek('2016-01-01');
```

result:

```
fn_yearofweek fn_yearofweek    fn_yearofweek 
------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
20151         201553           20161
```

Comment: Thanks alot @wingedpanther :)

Comment: Sorry for the two year later comment, but if creating this function in redshift, it should be `RETURNS TEXT IMMUTABLE AS $$` since the value should always be the same for the same inputs, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supports two types of "week" calculations. The ISO standard (which is what you *not* want) and a week numbering where the first week starts on the first day of the year.

These two can be obtained using the `to_char()` function (

```
select to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'WW') as week_january, 
       to_char(date '2015-12-31', 'WW') as week_december,
       to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'IW') as iso_week_january, 
       to_char(date '2016-12-31', 'IW') as iso_week_december
```

The above returns the following:

```
week_january | week_december | iso_week_january | iso_week_december
-------------+---------------+------------------+------------------
01           | 53            | 53               | 52
```

If you need that as a real integer rather than a string, just cast the result to `integer`, e.g: `to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'WW')::integer`

The format for `to_char()` is explained in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

---

As a side note: for the ISO week to work properly you would need to combine this with the ISO yearweek as well: `to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'IYYY')` will return `2015`